# Should an adult child live with parents?

Tags: adult-child

In India, it is a common practice for adults to live with their parents. Why is it frowned upon in USA? Is it a good practice?

Comment: Though an interesting question, this is more of [a discussion-type question](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), which is not on topic on SE sites. Please see the [help sections](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about what questions are on-topic on the site. If you can make it more about parenting and more specific/on topic, please do. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunaltely on hold, so a comment. There are three reasons to live with your parents: poverty, immaturity, and culture. The US are an individualistic culture, where personal independence is seen as a sign of maturity. To be respected, in the US you need to move out from your parents and build your own life. If you stay, this is seen as a sign of immaturity or poverty, both of which are shameful in the US. Other cultures are more family oriented and it is seen as mature if you *stay* with your parents (and grandparents, nephews etc.) and together with them work to build the family life.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Cultural differences in family relations have been well researched and this question can be answered objectively. I summarized the findings in my comment.

Comment: @what - the fate of comments is questionable. They have no sources, therefore are unvetable. The proper thing to do is to reopen, or post in meta (where you can campaign for reopening). Then answer with supportive sources. This is too POB to fly on opinion alone.

Comment: What's PQB? @anongoodnurse

Comment: Please go ahead and delete the question if it does not meet your standards. I am unable to do it as it has answers.

Comment: I think POB means primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 3):

Ahh. Culture. I think its less the fact that you're living with your parents, than *why*.

In india, in general you live with your parents (or live with you) often so you can take care of them. There's also a very different expectation of "private space" - kids tend to share rooms from what I've seen. You eventually move out when you get your own family, but at some point, grandparents move in and a extended, multigenerational family was a norm, least until very recently.

(In this case I'm speaking broadly. Please feel free to correct me in the comments) In the US, I'd suspect there's a perception that you're living with your parents cause *you can't move out*.  You may have a job, but there might be an idea that you're being at least a bit parasitic, or co-dependant with your parents.

That said, I *do* live with my parents, and the attitude between how people react to me when I was working for my folks (or as many assumed, not at all) and when I work elsewhere is very different. At some point I'm moving out (tho, I live in a small country), and while I'll be up to some stuff my parents wouldn't approve of in their house (like finally getting a small lathe!), I'll likely maintain fairly close links with them.